# How to wrap lists after 5 element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

We have an unordered list that will display up to 10 items. How can we setup the list so that it will place the first five items on the left and put the next five items into the next column (splitting equally)?

Here is the current and desired output. We tried to use [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), but cannot find a way to do it. Open to other ideas if flexbox cannot get it done.

Here is the current results and desired outputs. 
[image: output]

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li>Assertively mesh</li>
  <li>client-centered</li>
  <li>niches and covalent networks</li>
  <li>Uniquely e-enable</li>
  <li>team driven benefits</li>
  <li>rather than exceptional</li>
  <li>architectures Continually</li>
  <li>foster cutting-edge</li>
  <li>open-source core</li>
  <li>process-centric</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use CSS columns for this:

```css
ul {columns: 2;}
li {list-style-position: inside;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Assertively mesh</li>
  <li>client-centered</li>
  <li>niches and covalent networks</li>
  <li>Uniquely e-enable</li>
  <li>team driven benefits</li>
  <li>rather than exceptional</li>
  <li>architectures Continually</li>
  <li>foster cutting-edge</li>
  <li>open-source core</li>
  <li>process-centric</li>
</ul>
```

Note that 'display: grid' has [pretty bad browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20grid), while columns (and flexbox) [score better](https://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn).

Comment: I would love to know why someone put -1 for this post. It is completely useless without explanations.

Comment: I would like to know that too!

Comment: is there a reason when i run code snippet that the bullet points are not available in the second column? I prefer a solution with a better browser support.

Comment: If you want to retain the bullet points, then the rule `list-style-position: inside` should work, or potentially increasing the left margin/gutter of the second column.

Comment: @usernameabc try only 7 elements and see the result, correct if I am wrong, but you said *after the 5th element* and not *split the list equally*. If you only want to split the list then make it clear on your post and you will receive more answers with good support

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have added details about splitting equally. However, the `-1` without any explanations is not helpful. I will be marking this as the best answer because when try 7 elements or 10 elements, it splits it in a manner that we need. Additionally, this solution provides better ability for us to word wrap the text when the text is longer per `<li>` element.

Comment: @usernameabc so add a +1 and accept it and it will be good ;) let's don't make the `-1` a huge thing. the answer will get upvoted if it's useful

Answer (score 5):

To arrange content into predictable columns, each of five items, would seem to be a job for `display: grid`:

```css
ul {
  /* set the layout to grid: */
  display: grid;
  /* define the number of rows you
     require: */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  /* set the flow of the grid to follow
     a columnar layout: */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Assertively mesh</li>
    <li>client-centered</li>
    <li>niches and covalent networks</li>
    <li>Uniquely e-enable</li>
    <li>team driven benefits</li>
    <li>rather than exceptional</li>
    <li>architectures Continually</li>
    <li>foster cutting-edge</li>
    <li>open-source core</li>
    <li>process-centric</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6ndbmcsu/).

Although, if you really want to use flex-box, you *can*:

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  /* Use the flexbox layout: */
  display: flex;
  /* set the content direction to
     columns: */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* let the contents wrap to
     new columns once the
     boundaries of the element are
     reached: */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* set the height of the containing
     element, in order for the wrapping
     to occur: */
  height: 10em;
  /* entirely irrelevant: */
  list-style: none;
  max-width:500px;
}

li {
  /* set the height of the individual
     'rows' to be 20% of the total height
     of the parent, to enforce the five-
     items per 'column': */
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  width: 45%;
}

/* Irrelevant, but allows 'column-headings'
   to be styled: */
li:nth-child(5n + 1) {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Assertively mesh</li>
    <li>client-centered</li>
    <li>niches and covalent networks</li>
    <li>Uniquely e-enable</li>
    <li>team driven benefits</li>
    <li>rather than exceptional</li>
    <li>architectures Continually</li>
    <li>foster cutting-edge</li>
    <li>open-source core</li>
    <li>process-centric</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6ndbmcsu/1/).

Comment: the flexbox solution is a bit scrambled on small screens .. you meant probably `text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;` ?

Comment: @Temani: honestly, that was just left in from experimentation when I didn't want the overflow to be visible. It can absolutely be removed. If you have the inclination to edit to improve please do feel free! (It's getting late enough here in the UK that I should probably be in bed by now...) :)

Comment: @DavidThomas when i opened the JSFiddle, i noticed (browsers: Edge, IE, Chrome, Firefox) that for `breakpoints < 945px` in the result section there were word wrapping issues. For example, `niches and covalent networks` had `networks` word wrapping on top of `Uniquely e-enable` (which is the next `<li>` element). Is that happening to you as well?

Comment: It does, yes; there's a couple of ways to guard against the problem; the first is to [remove the `line-height: 2em` from the `<li>` elements](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6ndbmcsu/3/), and the second is - because the same problem will arise later, when the columns are too narrow to hold the content - *either* use [`overflow: hidden`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6ndbmcsu/4/) or use media breakpoints to adjust the sizing or layout of the `<li>` elements.

Comment: @usernameabc: my above comment timed-out for editing, so with regards to media-queries, one imperfect example is the following: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6ndbmcsu/5/